# What is an orthogonal form?

Tags: linear-algebra, grassmannians, schur-functions

I am reading the article: [Algebro - Geometric applications of Schur S- and Q-polynomials](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0083503)
On page 179, they said about an orthogonal form $\psi$ on $W$. There is no definition of an orthogonal form on the article, also on google. How an orthogonal form is defined? Is this a different name of an inner product?

Comment: Usually an orthogonal form is a symmetric bilinear form, as opposed to an inner product or unitary form, which is usually a conjugate-symmetric semilinear (= linear in one variable) form.